# get image and caption into one flex item?

Tags: css, flexbox

AI want to put an image and its caption into one flex-item and have several such flex-items in one flex-container. I want the image to be above its caption. But what happens is that each caption is *beside* its image. How do I get them one above the other?

I tried putting the captions into another flex-container below the images. But when the screen size is less wide, the images stack, then the captions stack instead of being image, then its caption, image, then its caption.

```
<div class="flex-item-popup" id="popup">
    <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-times-circle"></i></div>
    <h2></h2>
    <div class='text'></div>
    <div class="videos"></div>
    <div class="flex-container images"></div>
    <div class="flex-container captions"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 #popup {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#popup .close {
    /*position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;*/
    float: right;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}
#popup .close:hover {
    opacity: .7 !important;
}
.images, .captions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.images {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.images .flex-item, .captions .flex-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 300px;


}
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle of your work with some sample images and captions and stuff

Comment: @Sai: https://jsfiddle.net/auzwq4be/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` HTML5 tags. I am pretty certain that is going to help you and it is what you are looking for.

[Here is updated fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/auzwq4be/4/)

And the SO code snippet here...

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-item {
  /*width: 350px;
  height: null;*/
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.flex-item img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container images">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/morehouse/img/grads.jpg" />
      <!--<div style="clear: both;"></div>-->
      <figcaption>Our grads.</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/morehouse/img/building.jpg" />
      <figcaption>A building</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/morehouse/img/campus.jpg" />
      <figcaption>The campus.</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/morehouse/img/trio.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Three people</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That does stack them. Thanks!